# "Unfortunately, APP has stopped. Anyway to get rid of it with adb?

Tags: android, adb

I'm doing automation on my Android phone and sometimes the app crashes and I get "Unfortunately, APPNAME has stopped." Is there anyway to get rid of this message using adb?

Comment: You can inject a touch event, but you need to figure out the coordinates.  It's possible there's some key event that would do it but this may need research/experimentation.

Comment: wouldn't you want to stop your app from crashing?

Comment: @edthethird it's not my app. I'm automating another app

Comment: see if `service call activity 97` does what you want

Comment: @AlexP. is that an adb command? like `adb service call activity 97` ?

Comment: it's `adb shell service call activity 97`

Comment: @AlexP. unfortunately this does not do it

Answer (score 0):

-Take a look at your android logcat change dropdown(verbose->error) and it will 
 show exactly the line no of error
- wrap your code with try...catch block and print log message

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem while automating some test. The test was getting stuck until I click OK. So what I did was sending tap event to the emulator calculating where the OK button would be. This is what I did.

```
adb shell wm size
```

This will give you the device physical size. Then, computed the center of the screen by halving the X and Y and then used the following command to continuously send tap event to the emulator.

```
    while true; do adb shell input tap X Y; sleep 3; done
```

It worked fine for all the cases that I have. But it could be possible that the Y coordinate be shifted down if the name of the application is very long or sometimes you might have two buttons and hence the X coordinate shifted to the right.